# I've managed to pass two-arguments function, where one-argument function is expected

Tags: swift, function, types, currying

```
func curry<A, B>(_ f: @escaping (A) -> B) -> (A) -> B {
    print("is called")
    return f
}

func sum(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int {
    a + b
}

curry(sum)
```

It shouldn't even compile. But it compiles and the curry function gets called! 
`f` is inferred as `((Int, Int)) -> Int`

While the point of view of the compiler is pretty obvious here, it still feels like a bug...
And how am I supposed to prevent this situation to happen? I mean successfully passing parameters with, basically, not-matching types!

P.S. I was attempting to implement curry function in general form (with variadic type parameters) through recursion. The curry function provided above was intended to be the final step of the process. Hence the naming

Comment: You can avoid this by adding another overload `func curry<A, B, C>(_ f: @escaping (A, B) -> C) -> (A) -> (B) -> C`, but otherwise, no. It would be very hard to implement a general `curry` using parameter packs right now anyway. Parameter packs, as a language feature, still have lots of bugs and often crashes the compiler.

Comment: Yeah, I failed to implement it 

Comment: I think an expression macro could be a more suitable tool for this. You can do something like `#curry(sum, 2)`, with `2` being how many arguments to curry.

Comment: This definitely isn't a bug. Currying was [intentionally removed in Swift 3](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0002-remove-currying.md). The type of `sum` is `((Int, Int)) -> Int` and everything else flows from that, as you've found.

Comment: I recall this implicit tuple packing/unpacking behaviour w.r.t. closures was removed (or at least limited) in some Swift version a while ago. Is that not the case?